# How do i get public gist filename from github gist API

Tags: github-api, gist

i am trying to get filename from github gist API, the below output which i get while calling the gist api.But the problem is how do i get the filename from the output. because filename is under files, and i want to display filename. So how do i do that. I am new to API so only able to display url, id, etc.

```
 {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2",
        "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2/forks",
        "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2/commits",
        "id": "41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2",
        "node_id": "MDQ6R2lzdDQxZGE1NGIwMzk4Njg4NmUxYTRlNTdjOGNkYjM4ZGMy",
        "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2.git",
        "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2.git",
        "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2",
        "files": {
          "telegram-white.svg": {
            "filename": "telegram-white.svg",
            "type": "image/svg+xml",
            "language": "SVG",
            "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cmschandan/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2/raw/16b1aac41526997d87400f33ad9912d511faf7a4/telegram-white.svg",
            "size": 1266
          }
        },
        "public": true,
        "created_at": "2020-12-11T12:58:59Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-11T12:59:46Z",
        "description": "",
        "comments": 0,
        "user": null,
        "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/41da54b03986886e1a4e57c8cdb38dc2/comments",
        "owner": {
          "login": "cmschandan",
          "id": 21227329,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMjI3MzI5",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/21227329?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/cmschandan",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/cmschandan/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "truncated": false
      },
```

Comment: extract the keys from the `files` object. The answer depends on what programing language/tool you are using to make the request

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes, post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript then you can do something like this:

```js
// `getGitHubGist` is a function that I assume you already 
// implemented which fetches your desired gist.
const gist = await getGitHubGist();

// Get an array of filename strings
const filenames = Object.keys(gist.files);

// Get an array of all the file details
const files = Object.values(gist.files);
```